# When to create a custom datasource method as opposed to setting a variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have a datasource array, and I wish to feed it to my custom controller. There are two ways I can do this:

1) The obvious way is to create a property array that can be accessible outside of the class, and then I would simply set that property through the controller like so

```
[customController setDataSourceArray:myServerArray];
```

2) To create a datasource method along with all the other delegate methods that I've created with the signature looking something like this:

```
-(NSMutableArray)arrayForCustomControllerDataSource{
    return myServerArray;
}
```

and then I'd set the private property array with the returned array from the datasource method

Are there any advantages in using one method over the other? Is it more than just convenience or which looks better?

I'm assuming that you have finer control with the second method as you can then do some pre-configurations, reset the controller based on the returned array, but you can do the same by altering the setter property/method, and adding extra code inside it, so what is the real difference and when should I do which?

Comment: Is this just a question of using a synthesized getter or writing your own? If so, then I think you have answered your own question: if you need to do something to the array before you return in, then write your own getter. Otherwise, use the synthesized one.

Comment: Its a question on whether to create a datasource method that returns an array into my custom controller through a datasource method... or whether to populate the custom controller data array via a public property with a setter method. And asking what the differences are and when I should use what.

Comment: Aha, I think I understand. You're asking whether the controller should send a message to a data source asking for the array, or if the data source should set the array property on the controller?

Comment: @TomErikStøwer Yes, exactly. To be cool, and to also learn more about creating delegates and datasource methods, I ended up going with the datasource method way instead of setting the array property on the controller. I find that this would be more in line with the other cool custom delegates that I had going on. I realised that you need to create a new protocol for the datasource, with its own method definitions. Overall it was fun to do. The question still begs an answer though.  The only reason I can think of creating a datasource is if you need extra steps of execution, any other reason?

Answer (score 2):

The standard practice, as exemplified by UIKit's [UITableViewDataSource protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), is that the controller (or in the case of UITableView, the view) asks the datasource for the information it needs.

The data source will also typically be a property of the controller.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <CustomDataSource> dataSource;
```

So when the controller needs the data:

```
NSArray *myData = [self.dataSource customServerArray];
```